# В Unity при запуске игры часть экрана остается черной, и само окно игры уходит вниз, как это исправить?

Tags: unity3d, 2d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для камеры использую cinemachine.

Answer (score 0):

подергать ползунки viewport rect в main camera